# Vuetify- image Load failed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

What I want to do is display the image on the page. I have stored its path in backend(MySQL) and after fetching that I am putting it in src of `<v-img>` but the error occurs saying-

```
[Vuetify] Image load failed

src: userImage

found in

---> <VImg>
       <Anonymous>
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

**EDIT- this is my Profile.js file**

```
<template>
<v-container >
      <div class="headline">Your Profile</div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="title">Username-</div>
      <v-text-field
      v-model="user.username"
      placeholder="Username"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
    <div class="title">Password-</div>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="user.password"
      placeholder="Password"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
    <div class="title">Avatar-</div>
    <v-img
      v-bind:src="userImage"
      aspect-ratio="1"
      class="grey lighten-2"
      max-width="150"
      max-height="150"
    ></v-img>
    <div class="title">Email-</div>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="user.email"
      placeholder="Email"
      required
    ></v-text-field>

</v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: You need to show some code, not just error message....

Comment: sorry for that..

Comment: And the data ? What is the value of  `userImage` ?

Comment: userImage has the value as=`uploaded_images\users\main-thumb-394688203-200-tbjppbxdlfloldogbcqrvmrkwoxgnpom.jpeg`

Comment: Is this DEV environment we are talking about ? Is this image on the server ?

Comment: Yes sir.. the image is on the server.. I saved its path in database..

Comment: If the `userImage` variable had the value you are showing, the error message would be like `[Vuetify] Image load failed src: uploaded_images\users\main-thumb-394688203-200-tbjppbxdlfloldogbcqrvmrkwoxgnpom.jpeg` but `src: userImage` makes me feel you are __not__ binding src attribute...

Comment: after doing this `v-bind:src='userImage'` this error comes `src: uploaded_images\users\main-thumb-394688203-200-tbjppbxdlfloldogbcqrvmrkwoxgnpom.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to bind `src` attribute : `<v-image v-bind:src="userImage" />`

As you can see [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L212) and [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L181), the message is generated as a result of [`onerror`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) event raised by browser itself so this means something is wrong with the image URL (image with this URL is not on server). Check the URL rendered, try to copy it and open in browser...

Comment: hello @Jack. How did you resolve this issue. I'm having the same issue